# RxJS with immutable datastructures?

Tags: immutability, rxjs, immutable.js

I'm working through [RxJSKoans](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJSKoans) and I'm seeing a recurring pattern of feeding in array of results, that the subscriber pushes new values onto:

```
var Rx = require('rx'),
    Subject = Rx.Subject

var result = [];
var s1 = new Subject();
s1.subscribe(result.push.bind(result));
s1.onNext('foo');
result;  // ['foo']
```

This is clearly an impure function; the `result` array is mutated by subscribe.

I've seen [small-scale projects on Github](https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=rxjs+immutable) that make a stab at this using Immutable.js, but none is actively maintained.

Im wondering if there's a widely-adopted immutable implementation pattern, and if not, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't call it a pattern, but since you can pass everything through a stream you can also pass in any immutable data structure:

```js
const stream$ = Rx.Subject.create();

stream$
  .map(data => data.set('a', data.get('a') + 1))
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data));

stream$.next(Immutable.Map({ a:1 }));
stream$.next(Immutable.Map({ a:2 }));
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.7/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.js"></script>
```

Also, there is no reason to have `result` as an external state. This is what methods like [`scan`](http://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/scan.html) are for. This is would I would suggest you do to manage (internal) state:

```js
const stream$ = Rx.Subject.create();

stream$
  .scan((list, val) => list.push(val), Immutable.List())
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data));

stream$.next('foo');
stream$.next('bar');
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.7/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.js"></script>
```

Comment: I would warn though that some rxjs operators work with javascript arrays, and not with List. You then have to sandwich your flattening operator inside a rxjs `map` operator returning `data.toJS()`, and another doing `Immutable.fromJS(data)`. Won't happen that often though.